# unable to parse data by post method in a listview in android

Tags: android, listview, post, server

hey guys i tried to parse jason data from server by post method. i watched many tutorials on it but unable to got the exact solution. so please help me out . the code snippt is follow....

```
public class ServiceHandler1 {
     private  String apikey;
    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    public ServiceHandler1() {

    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setHeader("Authentication:" , apikey);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                httpGet.setHeader("Authentication:" , apikey);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
}
```

and the remaining part of my code are folllowing... plz help me out.

```
public class Home extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://api-11hr.anovatesoft.com/v1/list";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER = "contactnumber";
    private static final String TAG_POSTAL_CODE = "postalcode";
    SessionManager session;
    private  String apikey;

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        // Session class instance
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();


        // apikey
        apikey = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_api);



        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                        .getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                        .getText().toString();

                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Adds.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
                in.putExtra(TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler1 sh = new ServiceHandler1();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler1.POST);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER);
                        String postalcode = c.getString(TAG_POSTAL_CODE);

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);


                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Home.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item1, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                    TAG_CONTACTS }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                    R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

this is the session manager class where i store the apikey for specific session...

```
public class SessionManager {
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";



    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_api = "apikey";



    // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }
    /**
     * Create login session
     * */
    public void createLoginSession(String name, String apikey){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

        // Storing name in pref


        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_api, apikey);

        Log.d("Ausds...",apikey);






        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }


    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything
     * */
    public void checkLogin(){
        // Check login status
        if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }



    /**
     * Get stored session data
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();



        // user api key
        user.put(KEY_api, pref.getString(KEY_api, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }


    /**
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser(){
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();


        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Quick check for login
     * **/
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error? if yes please post the log here

Comment: @NeerajKumar  i got  a lank activity only.. and on Log there is a message shown.....    {"error":true,"message":"Api key is misssing"}

Comment: ur not passing apikey to ur  makeServiceCall() method

Comment: @NandakishoreShetty i create one more class named SessionManager... wait i'll update it in my code....

Comment: if u look at error msg, it is saying missing of api key , so try passing ur api key

Comment: i worked a lot  on this issue but unable to get solution... can u please provide me other way to fetch data by post method in a list view

Comment: As @NandakishoreShetty pointed out You are not sending api key. check sessionManager.getUserDetails() method as It may not be returning API Key.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to handle server response,

```
public String getWebServiceTask(String requestURL,JSONObject postDataParams)
{
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    int responseCode = 0;
    JSONObject responseObject = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic admin:123456");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");  
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.connect();

        if(postDataParams != null){
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(postDataParams.toString());
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
        }

        responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        }
        else {
            response="";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        responseObject=new JSONObject();
        responseObject.put(MICConstant.API_RESPONSE_CODE, responseCode);
        responseObject.put(MICConstant.API_RESPONSE, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    return responseObject.toString();
}
```

Comment: i used this code too.. but this is also not working.

Comment: what problem ur facing?

Comment: ya, how u handling server side?

Comment: at server side i used authentication by api key.... when a user login thn an api key is generated for a spacific user... and i  parse it in all activities to  fetch data for that specific user

Comment: This is working code but i am not very sure how it is handled in server side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83706/discussion-between-sanjeev-and-nandakishore-shetty).